# Angular - Firebase get userdata after redirect

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I currently try to refactor all the signInWithPopup methods with signInWithRedirect because its more user-friedly on mobile devices. Nevertheless when I try to retrieve the data after the redirect I am never able to get it. I even tried to set a timeout. Maybe some of you know the solution for my issue:
[Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking)

### My Service

```
  public loginWithGoogle(): Promise<firebase.UserCrendential> {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      return this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider).then(() =>
       this.angularFireAuth.auth.getRedirectResult().then(res => res));
  }
```

### Component

```
  // binded on a click event on the dom - just wanna log the data not more :(
  public loginWithGoogle(): void {
    this.loginService.loginWithGoogle().then(res => console.log(res))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect call lead to a reload of page, and on this reload signInWithRedirect is not called, its promise never resolved and then getRedirectResult() not reached.

You Should call this.angularFireAuth.auth.getRedirectResult() on constructor. When service loads from redirect it provides data, else return `{user: null}`. An [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydkztn)

Answer (score -1):

I've faced this before.

Here's a **workaround** if you're interested in one:

You can listen to the `authState` `Observable` on `AngularFireAuth`. Once you subscribe to it in the `ngOnInit` on your Component, after the redirect, the `authState` is going to change and would yield the logged-in user's details.

Something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
...

@Component({...})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(...public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,...) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) {
        console.log('User Details: ', user);
      } else {
        console.log('No user logged in as of now');
      }
    })
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: It works but not satisfied at all, why is there a getRedirectResult() function if it is not working? Furthermore my initial goal was to extend my service method to set a user document in firestore if there is not. So I want to encapsulate this logic all within a service and keep my components as dummy as possible.... I need to make an action explizit and only after I get the redirect result.

Comment: You could look at using the resolve function on the router that way you could on login and you go to a different route have it do x https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve Or you could encapsulate it in your auth guard where it does an async get of the user data in your service